# 3D transform not working on Firefox (example)

Tags: css, firefox

I can't transform an image with 3d transform in firefox but I can do it in chrome.

the code I used is this:

```
<div class="book"><img src="http://www.enderonline.es/productos/968-1_p.jpg"></div>

.book {
position: relative;
-moz-perspective: 100px;
-moz-transform: rotateY(-2deg);
-webkit-transform: perspective(100) rotateY(-2deg);
outline: 1px solid transparent;
box-shadow: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/SE9sG/

I've tried everything I could but still not working. any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're using `perspective` as a seperate CSS property. If you look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), you'll see that `perspective` is simply a "command" you can pass to `transform`.

Another point: if you look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) you'll see as of version 16 of firefox the `-moz` is no longer needed.

The fix is relatively simple, just do exactly as you've done for chrome (webkit) compatibility:

```
.book {
    position: relative;
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-2deg);
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm wondering why these docs say differently https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective